# Moving in a for-loop on button click

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am trying to create an activity in my Android apps which runs a previously created workout exercise by exercise. This activity basically gets the workout from the intent, creates an ArrayList of workoutitems from the database and then iterates through the ArrayList.

The issue is with the runInReps and runInTime methods. runInTime should get the duration of the exercise (works) and create a countdowntimer that counts down the duration. Once finished, it should show Done, and when clicking the nextRep button move to another set (or if there are none left, next exercise - that's done in the run method). That doesn't work - the while loop becomes infinite, no way of exiting it. And the timer never even starts.

runInReps should do something similar, only without the timer - on finishing a set, you should click the button and move to the next set. Once there are no sets remaining, you should move to the next exercise (that's done in the run method).

Can you point me in the right direction? 
Thank you!

```
package android.tomdoischer.workOutDroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class runWorkout extends AppCompatActivity {
    String workoutName;
    int setsRemaining;
    DatabaseHelperExercise db;

    TextView runNameOfExercise;
    TextView timeOrRepsRemaining;
    TextView exerciseRemaining;
    TextView reps;
    Button nextRep;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_run_workout);


        workoutName = getIntent().getStringExtra("WORKOUT_NAME");

        runNameOfExercise = findViewById(R.id.runNameOfExercise);
        timeOrRepsRemaining = findViewById(R.id.timeOrRepsRemaining);
        exerciseRemaining = findViewById(R.id.exerciseRemaining);
        nextRep = findViewById(R.id.nextRep);
        reps = findViewById(R.id.reps);

        System.out.println("reached ifs");

        if(workoutName != null) {
            System.out.println("reached run");
            run();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have not selected a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        // a method which reads individual workoutItems from the database and returns an ArrayList
        // of workoutItems
        ArrayList<WorkoutItem> workoutItems = createRunnableWorkout(workoutName);

        System.out.println("array created");
        // length of the workout
        int length = workoutItems.size();
        int count = 0;


        // running the whole arraylist item by item
        for (WorkoutItem item : workoutItems) {
            System.out.println("running item");
            if (item.getExercise().isMeasureTime()) {
                count++;
                exerciseRemaining.setText(String.format("%s / %s", String.valueOf(count), String.valueOf(length)));
                runInTime(item);
            } else {
                count++;
                exerciseRemaining.setText(String.format("%s / %s", String.valueOf(count), String.valueOf(length)));
                runInReps(item);
            }
        }

        // jumps to the finished workout activity, saves the workout name
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(runWorkout.this, runWorkoutDone.class);
        newIntent.putExtra("WORKOUT_NAME", workoutName);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }

    public ArrayList<WorkoutItem> createRunnableWorkout(String workoutName) {
        ArrayList<WorkoutItem> workoutItems = new ArrayList<>();

        db = new DatabaseHelperExercise(this);

        Cursor data = db.getDataWorkoutItems(workoutName);

        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This workout is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                WorkoutItem workoutItem = new WorkoutItem();

                boolean inTime;
                if(data.getInt(5) == 1) {
                    inTime = true;
                } else {
                    inTime = false;
                }

                workoutItem.setExercise(new Exercise(data.getString(2),inTime));
                workoutItem.setSets(data.getInt(3));

                if (workoutItem.getExercise().isMeasureTime()) {
                    workoutItem.setTime(data.getInt(4));
                } else {
                    workoutItem.setReps(data.getInt(4));
                }

                workoutItems.add(workoutItem);
            }
        }

        return workoutItems;
    }

    public void runInTime(WorkoutItem item) { //todo fix me
        // next button not pressed yet
        System.out.println("running runintime");
        setsRemaining = item.getSets();
        System.out.println("setsremaining " + setsRemaining);

        // set text fields
        runNameOfExercise.setText(item.getExercise().getName());
        reps.setText(String.valueOf(item.getReps()));
        timeOrRepsRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(setsRemaining));
        System.out.println("text set");

        nextRep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setsRemaining--;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("onclicklistener set");


        while (setsRemaining > 0) {
            System.out.println("in the while loop");
            CountDownTimer cTimer = new CountDownTimer(item.getTime() * 1000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    System.out.println("ontick");
                    timeOrRepsRemaining.setText(String.format("%s s", Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000)));
                    System.out.println("ontick finished");
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    System.out.println("finished");
                    timeOrRepsRemaining.setText("Done!");
                }
            };
            cTimer.start();
            cTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    public void runInReps(WorkoutItem item) { //todo fix me
        // next button not pressed yet
        System.out.println("running runinreps");
        setsRemaining = item.getSets();

        // set text fields
        runNameOfExercise.setText(item.getExercise().getName());
        reps.setText(String.format("%s reps", String.valueOf(item.getReps())));

        nextRep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setsRemaining--;
            }
        });

        while (setsRemaining >0) {
            timeOrRepsRemaining.setText(String.format("%s sets", String.valueOf(setsRemaining)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone has the same issue, the problem really was in trying to iterate through the ArraýList in a for- or while- loop. That's actually not what I wanted to achieve - I want to move in the ArrayList on button click.

See the fixed code for more details:

```
package android.tomdoischer.workOutDroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class runWorkout extends AppCompatActivity {
    String workoutName;
    int setsRemaining;
    boolean inTime;
    int move;
    int length;
    int count;
    DatabaseHelperExercise db;
    ArrayList<WorkoutItem> workoutItems;

    TextView runNameOfExercise;
    TextView timeOrRepsRemaining;
    TextView exerciseRemaining;
    TextView reps;
    Button nextRep;
    Button nextEx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_run_workout);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); // keeps the screen on

        workoutName = getIntent().getStringExtra("WORKOUT_NAME");

        runNameOfExercise = findViewById(R.id.runNameOfExercise);
        timeOrRepsRemaining = findViewById(R.id.timeOrRepsRemaining);
        exerciseRemaining = findViewById(R.id.exerciseRemaining);
        nextRep = findViewById(R.id.nextRep);
        nextEx = findViewById(R.id.nextEx);
        reps = findViewById(R.id.reps);

        System.out.println("reached ifs");

        if(workoutName != null) {
            System.out.println("reached run");
            run();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have not selected a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        // a method which reads individual workoutItems from the database and returns an ArrayList
        // of workoutItems
        workoutItems = createRunnableWorkout(workoutName);

        System.out.println("array created");
        // length of the workout
        length = workoutItems.size();
        move = 0;

        setUpTextViews(move);
    }

    public ArrayList<WorkoutItem> createRunnableWorkout(String workoutName) {
        ArrayList<WorkoutItem> workoutItems = new ArrayList<>();

        db = new DatabaseHelperExercise(this);

        Cursor data = db.getDataWorkoutItems(workoutName);

        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This workout is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                WorkoutItem workoutItem = new WorkoutItem();

                boolean inTime;
                if(data.getInt(5) == 1) {
                    inTime = true;
                } else {
                    inTime = false;
                }

                workoutItem.setExercise(new Exercise(data.getString(2),inTime));
                workoutItem.setSets(data.getInt(3));

                if (workoutItem.getExercise().isMeasureTime()) {
                    workoutItem.setTime(data.getInt(4));
                } else {
                    workoutItem.setReps(data.getInt(4));
                }

                workoutItems.add(workoutItem);
            }
        }

        return workoutItems;
    }


    public void onNextEx(View v) {
        move++;
        if(move<length) {
            setUpTextViews(move);
        } else {
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(runWorkout.this, runWorkoutDone.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("WORKOUT_NAME", workoutName);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
    }

    public void onNextSet(View v) {
        if (inTime) {

        } else {
            if(setsRemaining > 1) {
                setsRemaining--;
                timeOrRepsRemaining.setText(String.format("%s set(s)", String.valueOf(setsRemaining)));
            } else {
                timeOrRepsRemaining.setText("Done!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void setUpTextViews(int move) {
        runNameOfExercise.setText(workoutItems.get(move).getExercise().getName());

        setsRemaining = workoutItems.get(move).getSets();
        inTime = workoutItems.get(move).getExercise().isMeasureTime();

        if(workoutItems.get(move).getExercise().isMeasureTime()) {
            reps.setText(String.valueOf(setsRemaining) + " set(s)");
            new CountDownTimer(workoutItems.get(move).time * 1000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timeOrRepsRemaining.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " s");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    timeOrRepsRemaining.setText("Done!");
                }
            }.start();


        } else {
            reps.setText(String.valueOf(workoutItems.get(move).getSets()) + " rep(s)");
            timeOrRepsRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(workoutItems.get(move).getReps()) + " set(s)");
        }
        exerciseRemaining.setText((move + 1) + " / " + length);
    }
}
```